# TFS 2012 and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I was very excited to hear TFS 2012 made a step towards distributed source control in allowing source code to be modified (without major issues) when TFS is offline.

I currently use a hosted TFS service, so im hopeful the migration to TFS2012 should be painless. At least for me anyway.

So my question is simple, is there such a thing as TFS2012 powertools for VS2010 or is TFS2012 only available for VS2012?

Appreciate your comments.

Comment: You need to install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server 11 Compatibility GDR: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can connect to TFS 2012 from VS 2010, but you'll need the [compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082). Local workspaces (which support the improved off-line experience you described) are only supported in VS 2012 since they required significant client changes.

Comment: Yeah it was the local workspace support that I was specifically after, perhaps I should have mentioned that in my question. Thanks for your answer.