# team explorer for vs.net 2010 to connect to tfs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need a team explorer for vs.net 2010 to connect to tfs 2012. Is there such a thing  ?
If yes where can I download this?

Comment: [Team Explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329) + [TFS 2012 Compatibility GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS 2012 and VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111346/tfs-2012-and-vs-2010)

Comment: Not duplicate as other question talks about TF Service and not TF Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 you do not require any additional components to connect to TF Server 2012 it will connect natively.

If you are connecting to TF Service then you will need the Forward Compatibility GDR which adds support for authenticating over Microsoft ID (Was Live ID).